# What does a "OVM reboot" mean?

Tags: virtual-machine, oracle-vm-server

What does this term mean?

Comment: common, you will need to tell us more (at least where you see it) if you want an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVM probably means [Oracle VM](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/oraclevm/index.html) in case. So `OVM reboot` probably mean to reboot the virutal machine from Oracle VM Manager.